# Incoming connections getting blocked on some ports with no firewall rules Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I'm a relatively inexperienced Linux user and I'm having issues with connections to my machine.

I'm using Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

I have a web server, a samba server, a game server and a ssh server set up.
Everything used to work fine, until I did something that I'm not sure what. After a reboot some of the services are blocked. This could be the clue, I'm not sure.

I can only access the web server and connect to shh.
Samba and other ports are blocked/not working.
I've tried different suggested ways to diagnose issues relating to blocked ports, but everything seems to point that things should be fine.

ufw is disabled:

```
vilho@opti:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

iptables:

```
vilho@opti:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

netstat:

```
vilho@opti:~$ netstat -ltn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 10.8.0.1:53             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.24:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8125          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:19999         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7777          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7778          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7779          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:35693         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.24:8080       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32401         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 fe80::1b23:1994:7539:53 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 fe80::3617:ebff:febd:53 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::3617:ebff:febd:832:53 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::32400                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::25585                :::*                    LISTEN
```

But doing a nmap scan on my windows machine that lies on the same local network:

```
C:\Users\Vilho>nmap 192.168.0.24 -p 80,22,445,25585
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-04-03 00:42 FLE Daylight Time                                                        Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.24  
Host is up (0.0069s latency).  
PORT      STATE    SERVICE 
22/tcp    open     ssh
80/tcp    open     http
445/tcp   filtered microsoft-ds
25585/tcp filtered unknown
MAC Address: 34:17:EB:BD:83:27 (Dell)
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.78 seconds
```

This issue is really mystifying to me and I'm not sure how to continue from here.
What are the options for diagnosing this kind of issue. Are there some other firewall/software that could somehow be blocking these? Could there be a way to "follow" the traffic to see where the trail ends? Any other tips or ideas?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hello. A good start to any troubleshooting is complete info. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Hi. I'm currently using Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS. I'm adding that info to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to now be fixed. I unknowingly had nftables configured and enabled. Fixed it by modifying its config at `/etc/nftables.conf`

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. But in my case I don't have nfstable installed. I'm also using Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS, no iptables rules active and UFW disabled. Anybody has any tips ?

Comment: @marceloodir please ask a new question. This is a question answer site, not a discussion forum. See the site help on how to ask a question.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but I don't know how to check if nftables is enabled - can you add that to your answer? Also, you could improve your answer by describing _what_ exactly you fixed.